# Ruby method with optional options and &block parameter

Tags: ruby, methods, parameters, unary-operator

1. Hey there

   Is it possible to have optional attributes and a block as parameters
   for a method call?

   Example: I have to call

   ```
   method(foo, foo: bar, -> { do_something }
   ```

   and tried it with

   ```
   def method(foo, *bar, &block)
   end
   ```

   As for my understanding the block always has to be at last position?

   After a bit of research I found out the unary(?) `*` seems to be for
   arrays. Since I try to pass a `Hash` I changed the code to

   ```
   def method(foo, bar={}, &block)
   end
   ```

   But this doesn't do the trick either. I guess its because he cant
   figure out where the bar ends and the block starts.

   Any ideas or suggestions? Thank you in advance

   Append: Just for the curious why I need this. We have a big json
   schema running and have a small DSL that builds the json from the
   model definitation. Without going to much into detail we wanted to
   implement exportable_scopes.

   ```
   class FooBar
     exportable_scope :some_scope, title: 'Some Scope', -> { rewhere archived: true }
   end
   ```

   On some initializer this is supposed to happens:

   ```
   def exportable_scope scope, attributes, &block
     scope scope block
     if attributes.any?
       attributes.each do |attribute|
         exportable_schema.scopes[scope] = attribute
       end
     else
       exportable_schema.scopes[scope] = {title: scope}
     end
   end
   ```

   So this is working fine, I just need a hint for the method
   parameters.

Comment: I ting, you can use `exportable_scope(:some_scope, title: 'Some Scope'){ rewhere archived: true }`. You dont need to send block like parametter.

Comment: I think you're confusing passing a block with passing a callable object(lambda) as an argument, which what ActiveRecord `.scope` expects to receive. The body of the scope is required, so you can change your method signature to `exportable_scope(name, body, attributes = {})` and call `scope name, body`. Take a look at `.scope` definition here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/dc925119a3912ecfe0df400007163f33b99d6385/activerecord/lib/active_record/scoping/named.rb#L143. `exportable_scope :some_scope, -> { rewhere archived: true }, title: 'Some Scope'`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

When mixing different kinds of parameters, they have to be included in the method definition in a specific order:

1. Positional parameters (required and optional) and a single splat parameter, in any order;
2. Keyword parameters (required and optional), in any order;
3. Double splat parameter;
4. Block parameter (prefixed with &);

The order above is somewhat flexible. We could define a method and begin the parameter list with a single splat argument, then a couple of optional positional arguments, and so on. Even though Ruby allows that, it's usually a very bad practice as the code would be hard to read and even harder to debug. It's usually best to use the following order:

1. Required positional parameters;
2. Optional positional parameters (with default values);
3. Single splat parameter;
4. Keyword parameters (required and optional, their order is irrelevant);
5. Double splat parameter;
6. Explicit block parameter (prefixed with &).

Example:

```
def meditate cushion, meditation="kinhin", *room_items, time: , posture: "kekkafuza", **periods, &b
    puts "We are practicing #{meditation}, for #{time} minutes, in the #{posture} posture (ouch, my knees!)."
    puts "Room items: #{room_items}"
    puts "Periods: #{periods}"
    b.call # Run the proc received through the &b parameter
end

meditate("zafu", "zazen", "zabuton", "incense", time: 40, period1: "morning", period2: "afternoon" ) { puts "Hello from inside the block" }

# Output:
We are practicing zazen, for 40 minutes, in the kekkafuza posture (ouch, my knees!).
Room items: ["zabuton", "incense"]
Periods: {:period1=>"morning", :period2=>"afternoon"}
Hello from inside the block
```

Notice that when calling the method, we have:

- Provided the cushion mandatory positional argument;
- Overwritten the default value of the meditation optional positional argument;
- Passed a couple of extra positional arguments (zabuton and incense) through the *room_items parameter;
- Provided the time mandatory keyword argument;
- Omitted the posture optional keyword argument;
- Passed a couple of extra keyword arguments (period1: "morning", period2: "afternoon") through the **periods parameter;
- Passed the block { puts "Hello from inside the block" } through the &b parameter;

Please note the example above servers only to illustrate the possibility of mixing different types of parameters. Building a method like this in real code would be a bad practice. If a method needs that many arguments, it's probably best to split it into smaller methods. If it's absolutely necessary to pass that much data to a single method, we should probably create a class to store the data in a more organized way, then pass an instance of that class to the method as a single argument.